# String Break in XMl

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on xml files, as i have very lengthy xml and i need to use string breaker .so how can i use a string breaker in iphone development

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wtite your xml this way -

```
NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
    "<soap:Body>\n"
    "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
    "<Celsius>50</Celsius>\n"
    "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
    "</soap:Body>\n"
    "</soap:Envelope>\n";
```

Comment: no i want string breaker symbols after every tag to make my xml file linewise.

Comment: can you please post your xml file or explain your question bit more.

Comment: consider a xml file; @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<a>\n<b>%@</b>\n<c>%@</c>\n<d>%@</d>\n</a>....        how can i write this string in 2 lines.i mean what string breaker is used to write the above string in two or more lines